# Merge problems in mercurial because of wrong merge base: what's happening?

Tags: mercurial, merge, ancestor

I have a repository in which two revisions (14321 and 14319) share a parent (14318) - both changesets are **direct children** of 14318.  Nevertheless, the revision set query `ancestor(14321, 14319)` does *not* return 14318, but instead returns a much older changeset.  *What's happening?*

Screenshot in TortoiseHg:

[image: A diagram showing the odd results of query ancestor(14321, 14319)]

**Background:** I encountered odd merge conflicts recently that turned out to be caused by mercurial trying to re-apply changes that had already been merged.  I was able to track it down to an odd choice of merge base which caused both heads to include the same changes - but I don't understand why this happened and how I can prevent it in the future (I chose a DVCS partly to avoid these kinds of problems in the first place...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture shows there are not one but two common ancestors. So, it looks like a criss-cross merge case where merge problems arise from chosing one or another common ancestor.

References:

- https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1327#c18
- http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0504/2279.html
- http://wiki.vestasys.org/MergingFuture/Food4Thought/TrickyCases
- http://revctrl.org/CrissCrossMerge?action=recall&rev=11

There is a proposal for a new merge algorithm (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConsensusMerge). However, since Mercurial's 2.3 sprint this topic is stuck.

<del>To reduce this kind of problem, I suggest you to estabilish a client-server topology, so that developers only merge with the official repository. Maybe rebase could help also.</del>

A criss-cross merge is something like this:

```
   B --- D
  / \   / \
 /   \ /   \ 
A     X     F 
 \   / \   /
  \ /   \ /
   C --- E
```

In your case, it was:

```
           B
-----------o----               } stable/production
      C     \   \       F
------o------o---\------o      } default
       \     D    \    /
        -----------o---        } feature
                   E

A = ?
B = 14318
C = 14294
D = 14319
E = 14321
F = ?
```

To produce `F`, there are two possible circuits: `B-D-E-F` and `C-D-E-F`. Mercurial has chosen the latter.

You could have avoided the criss-cross if you haven't merged production and feature branches. 
The hotfix could have been propagated to the feature branch via the default branch. The log would be:

```
           B
-----------o               } stable/production
      C     \       F
------o------o------o      } default
       \    D \    /
        -------o---        } feature
               E
```

Comment: We are (almost always) using a client server topology - I don't see how that helps?  It's basically a 3-branch merge: there's a production branch with one hotfix changeset (14318): both other branches want this.  So they merge it: the default branch does this in 14319, and a feature branch does with 14321.  But when feature and default branches are themselves merged, you get something like the above screenshot.

Comment: Yep that's a good suggestion.  Of course, in reality it's a little more complicated; I've interpreted the branch names so they make sense when actually most commits were anonymous heads and later one happened to turn into a hotfix.  So for our group the problem was commits were in places they shouldn't have been and our branches were confusingly named (in retrospect) - but that's a bit out of scope?  Thanks for the update, it's definitely a lot more helpful this way!

Answer (score 0):

For incorrect base detection in case of common ancestor of mergesets one [weak point](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/what-is-the-algorithm-or-decision-process-used-by-mercurial-during-merge/2987#2987) is known:

it can be wrong if any of mergesets contains *unrelated to merge* edit

Answer (score -1):

I guess, that the ancestor is 14294. Since both of your new commits are merges, you now have more than one ancestor, which makes the choice ambiguous.

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell mercurial which of the potential ancestors to use.

Comment: Wrong... ancestor() is "**Greatest** common ancestor of the two changesets" according to help

Comment: @LazyBadger: Yeah, you're right, but it looks like their notion of Greatest is purely in the DAG sense - and 14294 and 14318 have no direct relationship.  Of course, it's still a poor guess to use 14294 since is older both temporally and much futher away in a graph-distance sense, but it's a understandable error for the algorithm to make.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - no. "Greatest" means **latest**

Comment: @LazyBadger: that's contradicted by the screenshot in the question - clearly, greatest doesn't necessarily mean latest.

Comment: Also what latest in what sense?  Timestap as per changeset?  Revision number?